# XSLT strip some strings and keep all tags

Tags: xml, xslt

In HTML I have this code:

```
<h1>1 Title with some <sup>extra</sup> tags.</h1>
```

XSLT function substring-after:

```
<xsl:variable name="title" select="fn:substring-after(normalize-space(.), ' ')"/>
```

strips first string, all tags and returns clear-text:

```
Title with some extra tags.
```

But, how would it be possible to get the result without first string, but with tags intact, like this:

```
Title with some <sup>extra</sup> tags.
```

I tried to use various functions on "node()" directly, but it seems, this is not the right approach. Is there anything else that can be done in such cases?

UPDATE:

The code below returns result with original h1 tags:

```
<h1>Title with some <sup>extra</sup> elements</h1>
```

With modified XSLT code h1 tags can be changed to title tags:

```
<title>Title with some <sup>extra</sup> elements</title>
```

The final XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="h1">
  <title>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </title>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="h1/text()[1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template to process the first text child node of the `h1` element with substring-after:

```
<xsl:template match="h1/text()[1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

With the identity transformation as the base transformation there would be nothing more you need, or depending on what you want to do with the `h1` element, simply a template matching it creating the output you want plus ensuring with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` that the child nodes are processed.

Comment: I checked the code and it works partially. Would it be also possible to modify it so the original h1 tags are replaced with new title tags like in example above?

Comment: @Futurion, it doesn't make much sense that you start with simple samples supposedly illustrating the question you have to change them drastically after you receive a question. If you want to transform `h1` elements into `title` elements then use `<xsl:template match="h1"><title><xsl:apply-templates/></title></xsl:template>`.

Comment: It seems my head is full so I'm making a mess, sorry. I fixed the code above, also posted the proposed result. Thank you again, your coding skills are amazing.